# Zomato API - search

Tags: api, zomato-api

When I try using the Zomato Search API request on location A, I get a result of 100 restaurants. But when I change my location to Location B, I get the same 100 restaurants I got for location A. Why is this happening all the time?

Also, for the geocode Zomato API, how many restaurants do I get close to the latitude and longitudes?

[image]

Comment: Can you provide your example API calls?

Comment: The location input can be specified using Zomato location ID or coordinates. Cuisine / Establishment / Collection IDs can be obtained from respective api calls. Get up to 100 restaurants by changing the 'start' and 'count' parameters with the maximum value of count being 20. Partner Access is required to access photos and reviews.

This is what the Zomato documentation says

Comment: When I enter the coordinated for Times Square and Central Park I get the exact same restaurant list, which is weird. Maybe because I got 100 restaurants from Times Square already? What exactly does the documentation mean? Is it 100 restaurants for a specific location or what?

Comment: I think the issue here is the two locations you are providing are very close to each other. Perhaps try with two locations that have a bit more distance and you will get a different response. If count is not specified, it will return 20. If count is specified, it will return that many, based on the parameters you have given. So if you have given a lat/long, it will find points close to that.

Comment: I have the same issue, when I change query in search request, always I get the same restaurants , Do you solve your issue??@Uddhav Bhagat